# Are there books on Regularization and Renormalization in QFT at an Introductory level?

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, renormalization, regularization

Are there books on Regularization and Renormalization, in the context of quantum field theory at an Introductory level? Could you suggest one?

*Added*: I posted at math.SE the question *[Reference request: Introduction to mathematical theory of Regularization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52139/reference-request-introduction-to-mathematical-theory-of-regularization)* and accepted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52139/reference-request-introduction-to-mathematical-theory-of-regularization/52146#52146) answer by Willie Wong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the following 3 articles and 2 books:

1. [Regularization Renormalization and Dimensional Analysis: Dimensional Regularization meets Freshman E&M](http://www.ate.uni-duisburg-essen.de/data/postgraduate_lecture/AJP_2011_Olness.pdf) Published in the american journal of physics (can be found also on hep-ph, but slightly different with less references)
2. [Regularization, from Murayama's course of QFT at Berkeley](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/230A/regularization.pdf)
3. [A Hint of Renormalization](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0212049)
4. A more general detailed, still introductory, treatment including renormalization would be the book [Renormalization Methods: A Guide For Beginners](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198506945)
5. A. Zee's book [QFT in a Nutshell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691140340)

Anyway, I hope that was useful

Revo

Comment: Thanks! It is useful indeed. I think the example of the infinite line of charge in the 1st article is a good starting point for me (as a retired electrical engineer) to learn with time this subject.

Comment: I have updated the 1st link, please recheck it, also here is another link for the same article which looks like slides for a talk http://www.hep.wisc.edu/cteq11/lectures/Olness_DimReg.pdf

Comment: Hadn't seen it before, but that note from the Berkeley QFT class is outstanding!

Answer (score 2):

See also my tutorial paper
 
[Renormalization without infinities - a tutorial](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/ms/ren.pdf),
which discusses renormalization on a much simpler level than quantum 
field theory.

Comment: http://vixra.org/abs/1003.0235 my paper on zeta regularization and resummation to obtain finite results for integrals.

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia Thanks for the link to your paper! I have seen your comment now.