# Theta-parameter vacuum energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, path-integral, quantum-chromodynamics

Suppose we have $\theta$-field in QCD (in a special case of constant $\theta$ it reduces to ordinary $\theta$ parameter):
$$
\tag 1 Z_{\theta} = \int D[\psi_{QCD}]e^{iS},
$$
where
$$
\tag 2 S = \int d^4x \left( \bar{q}\gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}q - \bar{q}^{i}M_{ij}q^{j} - \frac{1}{4g_{s}^2}GG + \theta G\tilde{G} + \text{gauge}+\text{ghost} \right),
$$
and $\psi_{QCD}$ are all fields which take part in QCD interactions.

I need to calculate $\theta$ parameter vacuum energy, more precisely, the quadratic term. In principle, from $(1), (2)$ it can be evaluated by computing quantity
$$
\tag 3 \frac{1}{2V_{4}}\int d^{4}xd^{4}y \left(\frac{\delta^{2}Z}{\delta \theta (x)\delta \theta (y)}\right)_{\theta = 0} \equiv \frac{1}{2V_{4}}\int d^4x d^4y \langle 0| G\tilde{G}(x)G\tilde{G}(y)|0\rangle_{\theta = 0} \equiv \frac{1}{2}\kappa (0),
$$
where $\kappa (0)$ is QCDs topological susceptibility. From $(3)$ it seems that coordinate dependence of $\theta$ doesn't play role; in particular, energy of constant $\theta$ term at zero momentum will be the same as of variable one.

But I've made following trick for evaluating $(3)$: I've made local chiral transformation $q \to e^{iC\gamma_{5}\theta (x)}q$, where $C$ is constant, and have get from $(1), (2)$ generating functional in a form
$$
Z_{\theta}[...] = \int D[\psi_{QCD},\theta]e^{iS{'}},
$$
where
$$
\tag 5 S{'} = \int d^4x\left( \bar{q}\gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}q - \bar{q}^{i}M_{ij}e^{2iC\gamma_{5}\theta(x)}q^{j} - \frac{1}{4g_{s}^2}GG + Ci\partial_{\mu}\theta J^{\mu}_{5}+ \text{gauge}+\text{ghost} \right)
$$
In the case of constant $\theta$ the fourth term is absent. Now I can substitute $(5)$ into $(3)$. After tedious calculations I will get that in compare to the case of constant $\theta$ I will also get extra term
$$
E_{2} = \frac{1}{2V_{4}}\times 8C^2\int d^4x d^4y\delta (x - y) \langle 0|\bar{q}^{i}M_{ij}q^{j} |0\rangle ,
$$
which comes from the initial correlator
$$
\frac{1}{2V_{4}}4C^2 \int d^4y d^4x \langle 0|T\left( \partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}_{5}(x)\bar{q}^{i}\gamma_{5}M_{ij}q^{j}(y)\right)| 0\rangle
$$
and almost coincides with corresponding term $E_{1}$ for constant $\theta$:
$$
E = E_{1} + E_{2}
$$
So or I've made the mistake in the statement that the vacuum energy of $\theta$ field at zero momentum doesn't depend on its coordinate dependence, or I've made incorrect calculations, or my result is true.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

**An edit**

It seems that calculations given above contain serious error. It is closely related to this question,
[Time-ordered product vs path integral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/223678/time-ordered-product-vs-path-integral), 
because in the calculations above I first used path integral approach, while later I used canonical operator formalism. The problem is that $(3)$ is true in path integral approach but isn't true in canonical operator formalism, while the next expressions are true in canonical operator formalism, but aren't true in path integral approach. I need to use path integral formalism if I want to compute explicit form of $(3)$; in this approach I may simply throw out derivatives, and contact terms don't arise; otherwise for working in operator formalism I need to derive the correct form of $(3)$ which includes contact (so-called Schwinger) terms, and they will coincide boundary terms like $(2)$.

Comment: Is there any motivation for this? Obviously, there are theories (axions) with a space-time dependent $\theta$, but the vacuum still corresponds to a constant value of $\theta$. Also, I don't understand your notation. Does $D[\psi,\theta]$ mean that you wish to integrate over $\theta$?

Comment: @Thomas : The vacuum corresponds to zero momentum modes of $\theta$, yes. But if you assume that initially $\theta$ is varying, then extra contribution $\partial_{\mu}\theta J^{\mu}_{5}$ occurs (this interaction is rised even on perturbative level), and it will make contribution in zero momentum summands since its correlator with $G \tilde{G}$ is not zero.

Comment: @Thomas : "...Does $D[\psi,\theta]$ mean that you wish to integrate over $\theta$?.." Yes, I mean that.

Comment: I don't get that. If you integrate over $\theta$, then the partition function no longer depends on it, and it does not make sense to functionally differentiate.

Comment: @Thomas : So you mean that
$$
Z[\theta] = e^{W[\theta , U, U^{\dagger}]},
$$
now I understand. THank you, I'll make corrections in the question body.

Comment: Either $Z=\int d\theta d\psi$ or $Z[\theta]=\int d\psi$.