# Feynman graphs in noncommutative quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, path-integral, feynman-diagrams, non-commutative-theory

I learn noncommutative quantum field theory now. Here, this topic is treated:
[arXiv:hep-th/0109162](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0109162)

I understood basic equations, but I don't really understand Feynman rules for noncommutative case. I have the following questions:

1. Considering the action $S$ of a nonc. model (e.g. Moyal product model) and now I split the action like this: $$S = \int_{0}^{T_1} dt \int d^3x L + \int_{T_1}^{T_2} dt \int d^3x L.$$ If I compute $e^{iS}$ can I write
   $$e^{iS}=e^{i\int_{0}^{T_1} dt \int d^3x L }e^{i\int_{T_1}^{T_2} dt \int d^3x L}$$
   or is the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula required? The noncommutativity in Moyal product theory concerns only the change of multiplication order of fields, but is every multiplication in such a theory dependent on order? Is in a Moyal product theory 
   $$e^{iS} = e^{i\int_{0}^{T_1} dt \int d^3x L } \star e^{i\int_{T_1}^{T_2} dt \int d^3x L}$$
   Or can I treat an action like it is commutative?
2. Planar graphs and nonplanar graphs: Why in noncommutative graphs one has two lines parallel to each other but one with opposite direction of the other? How such graphs can be obtained?

Answer (score 7):

1. Often when physicists refer to [non-commutative field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_quantum_field_theory), they are talking about a star product $\star$ within the Lagrangian density, e.g. non-commutative $\phi^4$-theory is
   $$ {\cal L}~=~-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu} \phi  ~\partial^{\mu} \phi -\frac{1}{2} m^2\phi^2 - \frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi\star\phi\star\phi\star\phi, $$
   i.e. upstairs$^1$ in the [path integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation).

   The star product $\star$ is often assumed to be non-commutative only in spatial directions. Then the star product $\star$ does not interfere with the time-slicing/ordering prescription in the path integral, and there will be no $\star$-differentiations downstairs in the path integral. See also e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/223695/2451) and links therein.
2. [Planar](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=planar+diagram) non-commutative Feynman diagrams use ['t Hooft's double index/line notation](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=hooft+double+notation+diagram). This makes sense because the star product $\star$ may be viewed as multiplication of (possibly infinite-dimensional) matrices. The momentum $p=\ell_a-\ell_b$ in a double-line propagator is the difference between the momenta of the two single-lines. In this way the overall momentum conservation is automatically implemented, and vertices take a simpler form.

--

$^1$ A correlator function $\langle F \rangle$ in the path integral formulation is  schematically of the form $\langle F \rangle=\frac{1}{Z} \int F e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S}$. The words *downstairs* and *upstairs* refer to $F$ and $S$, respectively, for hopefully obvious reasons.