# Vacuum expectation value of the derivatives of a scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, perturbation-theory

I am trying to calculate the vacuum expectation value of the time order of a product of the derivative of a scalar field
$$
\langle T \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi \rangle.
$$
Using the canonical formalism and part-integral formulation seemingly leads to different results.

Gerstein et. al once addressed this issue in
["Chiral Loops Ira S. Gerstein, Roman Jackiw, Benjamin W. Lee, and Steven Weinberg
Phys. Rev. D 3, 2486, 1971"](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.3.2486). It is claimed —without any proof— that via defining
$$
\Delta_{\mu\, \nu}(k)\equiv \int d^4 x e^{i k x} \langle T \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi \rangle
$$
we get
$$
\Delta_{\mu\, \nu}(k) = i \dfrac{k_{\mu} k_{\nu}}{k^2+i \epsilon} -i g_{\mu 0} g_{\nu 0}.
$$
As discussed by the authors, using the "naive perturbation theory", we miss non-covariant contribution to the propagator.

The question is that what is wrong with conventional perturbation theory that leads to this mistake.

PS: One may find this question relevant: [Time ordering and time derivative in path integral formalism and operator formalism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71987/290486a)

Comment: also relelvant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332316/84967