# Good reference for renormalization

Tags: resource-recommendations, renormalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there books on Regularization at an Introductory level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12385/are-there-books-on-regularization-at-an-introductory-level)

I am looking for a good introduction to renormalization (group). I have read several books about it but never really understand the idea. I know that the rough idea is to introduce the bare mass etc to absorb infinite integrals in perturbation theory. But my understanding stops at this point. I would really appreciate your help.