# Resource recommendation for Renormalisation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, path-integral

I am learning renormalization by myself. I aim to understand one-loop calculations in $\phi^4$ theory in d dimensions and one-loop calculations in Quantum Electrodynamics. I have looked at Peskin and Schroeder but find it tough to follow. Are there any better books or lecture notes to accomplish this?

Comment: P&S's explanation is as good, if not better, than anything else you will find. It will probably help if you let us know where you are stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/743/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12385/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I am not able to follow the mathematics in chapters 6 and 7.